We have used iframe API to embed the youtube Video somehow it gives a refresh or reload only the video section
We have built a custom component using youtube js and we have an option to play video inline or general modal popup.
When playing inline option enable it first loads the frame and refresh only video section and reloads the frame/video thumbnail. Since I used autoplay - no. So first it loads the thumbnail and play icon on thumbnail.
Im using below script : 
I tried overriding the onYouTubeIframeAPIReady method params also tried to just add iframe tag with all options but which ever option the refresh didnt stopped.

Please [edit] and add the code you're using.
